# Iterate through DynamoDBQueryExpression results without going over capacity limits

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a DynamoDB table that could contain upwards of 100,000 entries. I have a query expression that I'd like to run against this table which could return up to 5,000 entries.  After I get this response list then I'm going to iterate through it and perform certain operations on each entry.  So far this is what I have:

```
DynamoDBQueryExpression<...> query = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<...>();
DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper();

PaginatedList<..> results = mapper.query(Item.class, query);

for (Item item : results) {
    item.doStuff();
}
```

I have read and write capacities of 20 and I need to make sure that I don't surpass those limits.  How can I do that? Is there a way to change the query or PaginatedList so that it doesn't return results at a speed faster than 20 capacity units?

Answer (score 0):

Use `DynamoDBQueryExpression.withLimit` to limit the number of items returned by each API call. This will help you "guide" the provisioned throughput when you iterate the paginated result.

withLimit is tricky, and you should keep in mind and read again-and-again that it limits the returned items per-api-call and not the items returned by a `Query` call.